# Istanbul-tools installation error: github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto/bn256/cloudflare.gfpMul: relocation target runtime.support_bmi2 not defined

Tags: bash, go, command-line, ethereum, go-ethereum

I am trying to install Istanbul-tools to run an IBFT ethereum network as shown in this tutorial here https://medium.com/getamis/istanbul-bft-ibft-c2758b7fe6ff

I am installing istanbul-tools via their makefile using

```
go build -v -o ./build/bin/istanbul ./cmd/istanbul
```

After fixing some initial issues, as the code base hasn't been updated in a year, I then received the following error:

```
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto/bn256/cloudflare.gfpMul: relocation target runtime.support_bmi2 not defined
```

I also cannot find the Cloudflare file in any location in the go-ethereum folder. Can someone point me in the right direction? Cheers!

Comment: Did you get an answer for this or does the new answer help?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue, the issue has to do with your Ethereum/Istanbul Versions.  You either need to make sure everything is upgraded all the way, or downgrade Go.  I downgraded my go version to 1.10.3 and it worked.

Can you be provide more details on the specific Cloudflare file you are looking for?  There is a folder for Cloudflare within crypto/bn256 (full path is go-ethereum(or project name)/crypto/bn256/cloudflare) in the Main Ethereum project, I would check there for Istanbul.